# Good way to make a multi dimensional array without numpy

Tags: python, arrays

I need some way to keep track of a four dimensional array of boolean flags.  Just True/False values.  It seems that numpy is the canonical way to do such things, but it seems rather more complicated to install than I really want to deal with.  (I need to work in multiple OS environments.)

So, is there a straightforward way, or simple module, that would let me store and fetch True/False values from a four dimensional array without digging myself a mound of spaghetti deeper than the ocean?

I could do a list of lists of lists of lists, but that seems rather clumsy.

Comment: If I *had* to implement this myself, I might create a class wrapper around a `bytearray` -- override `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` to point to the proper location.  Of course, this gets more complicated if you want to support slicing, etc. -- Ultimately though, I think I'd just use `numpy` ;-)

Comment: What are your required operations?   Can you get away with a dict with 4-tuple keys?

Comment: you know, it's not really that hard to install numpy ...

Comment: You know it really IS that hard to install numpy.  On 64 bit Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the array is sparse (rare True values); you could use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = defaultdict(bool)
a[i,j,k,m] = True
```

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is to store and get from a 4-dimensional object, perhaps use a dict:

```
In [7]: x = {}

# store
In [8]: x[1,2,3,4] = True

# get
In [9]: x[1,2,3,4]
Out[9]: True
```

Comment: This is so simple but awesome.

Answer (score 1):

you could just use python lists in place of numpy arrays to generate a multi-dimensional array.

Something like:

```
values = [[[[True, False, False], [False, False, False], ...]]]
```

What other features of numpy arrays would you be using? If you need quite a few it should be simple to install on most platforms. Most Linux distros have it somewhere in their package management schemes, there is a "next, next, next, install" installer for windows and you can use PIP or similar to install on OS X.

As others have suggested an alternative is to use a `dict`, or possibly `defaultdict` and index into it with a tuple:

```
values = {}

values[1, 2, 3, 4] = True
...
```

Comment: That is basically the Mount Spaghetti that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: How are you loading data into the arrays?

Comment: the installer for windows only works on 32 bit windows.

And so far as I can predict, I just need to set, unset, and fetch the flags. (So numpy is probably serious overkill anyway.)

Comment: It should work on 64 bit windows too, but I believe it requires a 32 bit installation of Python. Which often amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately I will need to load the array one value at a time.  My data set appears to have absolutely no associations from one value to another.  yah.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
def make_array(shape):
    data = False
    while len(shape) > 0:
        data = [data for x in range(shape[-1])]
        shape.pop()
    return data



>>> make_array([3,4,5])
[[[False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False
, False], [False, False, False, False, False]], [[False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, Fa
lse, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False]], [[False,
 False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False]]]
>>>
```

You could do `shape[0]` to transpose the output shape. Of course this just gets you the "empty" array.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def make(depth):
    return defaultdict(lambda: make(depth - 1)) if depth > 1 else False

>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: make(4))     
>>> d[1][2][3][4] = True
>>> d[1][2][3][4] 
True
>>> d[1][2][3][2]
False
>>> d[1][2][3]
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10d08d488>, {2: False, 4: True})
```